# How to load the same page after registration using django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have this code in view.py

```
def room(request, room_name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('<str:room_name>/')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
```

[image]

and this is my url.py

```
path('<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
```

[image]

How to load the same page after registration using django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass some url to the `redirect` function. You can pass current path to `redirect` by using `request.path`:

```
def room(request, room_name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        # return http response for get request.
        return render(request, 'some_template.html', {})
```

Further read: Django docs on [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) and  [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).